# "Connection already closed" exception when performing a handshake using Python Websocket-client

Tags: python, websocket

I am looking to pull live data from the website colonist.io via a Python websocket-client connection. I have been following this guide: https://towardsdatascience.com/websocket-retrieve-live-data-f539b1d9db1e

I would like to be able to receive the Json files through the websocket connection opened here:

[image: Colonist io json files]

Using Chrome developer tools I can use this Header data to try to perform a handshake:

[image: Colonist io header]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from websocket import create_connection
import json

# Copy the web brower header and input as a dictionary
headers = json.dumps({
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'Upgrade',
    'Cookie': 'GA1.2.1115491479.1591113841',
    'Host': 'colonist.io',
    'Origin': 'https://colonist.io',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'JTMKPgxW1DE0DqJzrJ59fQ==',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
    'Upgrade': 'websocket',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'
})

# Launch the connection to the server.
ws = create_connection('wss://colonist.io/',headers=headers)

# Perform the handshake.
ws.send(json.dumps({"id": "1", "data": True}))

# Printing all the result
while True:
    try:
        result = ws.recv()
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

However, I am getting the exception "Connection is already closed." Full stack:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Josh/Documents/Anaconda/Euler/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Josh/Documents/Anaconda/Euler')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 668, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Josh/Documents/Anaconda/Euler/untitled0.py", line 31,
>   in 
>       result = ws.recv()
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_core.py",
>   line 314, in recv
>       opcode, data = self.recv_data()
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_core.py",
>   line 331, in recv_data
>       opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_core.py",
>   line 344, in recv_data_frame
>       frame = self.recv_frame()
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_core.py",
>   line 378, in recv_frame
>       return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_abnf.py",
>   line 361, in recv_frame
>       self.recv_header()
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_abnf.py",
>   line 309, in recv_header
>       header = self.recv_strict(2)
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_abnf.py",
>   line 396, in recv_strict
>       bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
>
> File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_core.py",
>   line 453, in _recv
>       return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket_socket.py", line
>   115, in recv
>       "Connection is already closed.")
>
> WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.

I was told by the author of the guide that my website may need some cookie information in the header for the handshake to be authenticated. I added the "Cookie" line but I'm not sure I've done this correctly or what he means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the __full__ error message into your question.

Comment: That is the full error message. But I've added the full stack trace if that's what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Is your Python code logged in to colonist? Seems ulikely you'll get any data without logging in - a requests session is likely to be your best route, successful login will likely get you a cookie in the session, or a header with an auth token. There's a requests api to retrieve/get at the cookies.